# How do I override a core constraint on an entity?

Tags: hooks

I want to replace one of core's constraints, `UserMailUnique`, with a custom validator.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hook_validation_constraint_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_validation_constraint_alter/).

Use the `id` in the annotation of the Constraint you are trying to override:

```
function MYMODULE_validation_constraint_alter(array &$definitions) {
  $definitions['UserMailUnique']['class'] = '\\Drupal\\MYMODULE\\Plugin\\Validation\\Constraints\\MyClass';
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is one way, overriding the plugin class system-wide. The question, however, points more to the entity level where you can override constraints added to entities in hook_entity_type_alter or hook_entity_base_field_info_alter. Then you can use a custom validator with a custom plugin ID defined in the class annotations.